What is the stance of Christianity on discussing philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?
What are the rules or guidelines on how a Christian should engage with others who would like to discuss philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?

Are Christians allowed to discuss / engage in the ideas to some degree? Or is it shunned.
How does Christianity incorporate ideas outside the main canon / system? (Generally speaking)
Are certain topics to be never discussed?

This would help me ask better questions to the Christianity community in general, but also would serve as a gauge as to how to interact. Basically, what is acceptable conversation topics in the end.

Christians love discussing pretty much everything. Nothing's off topic. But if you're asking specifically about this site, please see What types of questions can I ask on this site?

I am not asking about this site, I just want to know what is off topic for christians, and what the rules are for discussing things not in their system?

Then the answer is easy: nothing!

With respect to this question, the word "Christianity" is far too broad. There are many many different denominations with just as many different beliefs. The most wishy-washy would welcome such discussions and opportunities to learn new ways of worshiping; the most strict would be abhorred by the thought. If you have some specific denomination in mind, please state it in the question. ¶ Or perhaps it is asking about the best ways to reject someone's offer to talk about their religion?

IMHO: Beware any religion (cult) that discourages investigating other religions. Evil loves darkness; ignorance is darkness. Christianity is about Truth. To be sure, Christianity teaches that many ideas from other religions are wrong, but it doesn't discourage being aware of them. (Paul evidently studied other religions. My Christian college taught classes on world religions.) The line would be when you try to import these counter-Scriptural ideas into your own beliefs, or to try to bring other Christians to believe the same.

I am asking on all the 5 main religious SE's (judaism, christianity, islam, hinduism, buddhism), and for example on the judaism question, someone responded with an answer: "one should avoid thoughts that challenge core principles of the Torah, as human understanding is limited, and unrestricted speculation could lead to heresy and moral decay." So that is the kind of stuff I'm looking for, what is basically off-topic in christianity.

There is no prohibition on Christians discussing ideas or beliefs from other religions. Indeed, the Bereans were praised for checking everything they heard to make sure that it was sound.
BUT there is a danger of being led astray when delving deeply into other religious beliefs, or even different theologies within Christianity.  A Christian must be aware of heresies that lurk within other belief systems if they are to avoid being drawn in to error.
Here are some Christian guidelines:

J.I. Packer on Heresies: “Since it is beyond the wit of man to invent a new heresy, it is a great help to know the old ones, so that one can spot them when they reappear in modern make-up.”


Athanasius, 'Against Heresies', (circa 300 C.E.): “Error, indeed, is never set forth in its naked deformity, lest, being thus exposed, it should at once be detected. But it is craftily decked out in an attractive dress, so as, by its outward form, to make it appear to the inexperienced (ridiculous as the expression may seem) more true than the truth itself.”

Before delving deeply into other beliefs, first have a rock-solid theological foundation based on Christianity so you can recognise heresies that have been around since the first century.

Up-voted +1. Yes, one has to avoid giving a platform to heresies, either externally, among others, or internally, within oneself. Agreed.

More or less what I would said. There is no subject that must be avoided. (Unlike the Jews for example who are strictly forbidden from entertaining wicked thoughts)

There is a distinction to maintain between conversation about and participation in differing ideologies and religions. A mature Christian, one well versed in Scripture and the Christian experience which comes through the indwelling Holy Spirit in application of Scriptural truth in thought and deed, should have no need to fear any conversation.
Virtually anything may be taken as an opportunity to understand the viewpoint of another, make a personal connection and, thereby, perhaps find a personalized presentation of the Gospel.
There are conversations which will prove unprofitable and, the Christian's standpoint should be one of unfeigned love, but knowing that God is working everywhere to draw men to Christ coupled with an assurance that Christ will not allow any of His own to be lost should allay any fears.
